# sandboxed embeds if not allowed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, sandbox

I am trying to embed this video into my iframe and block the ads from that site by adding sandbox attributes, but it seems it is not working.

```
<iframe
  sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"
  src="//goload.pro/streaming.php?id=MjM5MzA=&title=Hyouka+Episode+1&typesub=SUB"
  width="500"
  height="300"
/>
```

Here's the link: `https:////goload.pro/streaming.php?id=MjM5MzA=&title=Hyouka+Episode+1&typesub=SUB`

How can I do this correctly?